# Determine the maximum and the minimum of an expression

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z \in \Bbb R, x,y,z \gt 0$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. Determine tha maximum and the minimum possible values of the expression
$$\frac {x^3+y^3+z^3} {x+y+z}.$$

Comment: do you know / are you allowed to use polar coordinates?

Comment: Yes, I know and I am allowed @GCab

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49211/prove-that-3a3b3c3-abca2b2c2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) implies that
$$3(x^3+y^3+z^3)\ge (x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2).$$
So the minimum is $\frac13$, attained when $x=y=z$.

Since obviously $x,y,z\in(0,1)$,
$$\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{x+y+z}<1\tag1.$$
On the other hand, if we set $y=z=\varepsilon$ and $x=\sqrt{1-2\varepsilon^2}$, then
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{x+y+z}=1.$$
That proves the upper bound $1$ in (1) is sharp and the said function does not have a maximum.

Comment: The first inequality is directly Chebyshev's +1.