# inequality proof $3*(a^3+b^3+c^3) > (a+b+c)*(a^2+b^2+c^2)$

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove the inequality 3*(a^3+b^3+c^3) > (a+b+c)*(a^2+b^2+c^2)

where a,b,c are positive and unequal.

RHS = a^3+b^3+c^3+ab*(a+b)+bc*(b+c)+ac*(a+c)

so the inequality reduces to proving

2*( a^3+b^3+c^3) > ab*(a+b)+bc*(b+c)+ac*(a+c)

This is where I got stuck , how to prove this ? , please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $3(a^3+b^3+c^3) > (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49211/prove-that-3a3b3c3-abca2b2c2)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$a^3+b^3>ab(a+b)$$ since we have
$$(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)>ab(a+b)$$

Comment: ok , got it , very elegant solution , Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Assume WLOG that $a\le b\le c$.
Then $a^2\le b^2\le c^2$.

Hence, it follows from Chebychev’s inequality that
$$3\cdot (a\cdot a^2 + b\cdot b^2 + c\cdot c^2)\ge (a+b+c)\cdot(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$

**Note:** if $a_1\le a_2\le\cdots\le a_n$ and $b_1\le b_2\le\cdots\le b_n$, then Chebychev’s inequality says that
$$n\cdot\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i\ge\sum_{i=1}^na_i\cdot\sum_{i=1}^nb_i$$

Comment: ok got it , I got to know about Chebychev’s inequality as well - Thanks.